# bgColor not updating via JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Why does the background color of the div not update?

```
Tagger.prototype.mouseDown = function(event) {
  this.element.style.posLeft = event.clientX;
  this.element.style.width = 200 + "px";
  this.element.style.height = 200 + "px";
  this.element.style.position = "absolute";
  this.element.style.zIndex = 10;
  this.element.style.bgColor = "yellow";
  console.log(this.element);
  console.log(this.element.style.bgColor);
}
```

The console output is:

```
<div id="tagbox4" class="tagbox" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; position: absolute; z-index: 10;">
yellow
```

I can select the div by inspecting the element in the browser, but it has no background color, even though the console says it is "yellow".

Comment: ...and again I'll suggest using a library for such manipulations. Using jQuery `.css()` with a property map is a breeze - last example on http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2

Comment: There is no `bgColor` in CSS...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not bgColor, that is an old outdated way of setting background colors when CSS was not popular.

You want to set the CSS property [background-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-color). When you set it with JavaScript, you remove the dash and use camelCase. So you want to set backgroundColor.

```
this.element.style.backgroundColor
```

Answer (score 4):

The name of that [css property is `backgroundColor`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSS2Properties-backgroundColor), not `bgColor`.

Your console says `"yellow"` because it reads the `bgColor` property - which just doesn't affect the displaying - and is also not contained in the style attribute you logged with the element's source.